# Reset dropdown at page refresh or back/forward browser navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a simple command to restart all, or some included javascripts? The problem I´ve got is that by refreshing page or pressing the back/forward key in the browser, some javascripts look like cached.

Maybe like codepen it does?

**UPDATE:**
I found out, that this is only a problem for my "dropdowns". So I have to reset them, if I refresh the browser and/or press back/forward. Any simple way?

**UPDATE:**
Ok, that works for me:

```
$(':input').not(":button").val('');
  });
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't retain state between page reloads.  When you reload a page, the code on that page reloads as well.  Can you show something which actually demonstrates the problem you describe?

Comment: So, what you want is not to "restart" is to keep some information? You could use cookies on server side or try with localStorage

Comment: No, I found out that this is a "dropdown" problem - so, I want to reset them by browser refresh and/or forward/backward.

Answer (score 3):

> No, I found out that this is a "dropdown" problem - so, I want to
>   reset them by browser refresh and/or forward/backward.

To reset dropdowns to default value, you could use:

```
$(window).on("pageshow", function() {
    $('select').prop('selectedIndex', function () {
        var selected = $(this).children('[selected]').index();
        return selected != -1 ? selected : 0;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the browser used a cached version of the page when you clicked the back button, it is called a `bfcache`.

You could try to add an empty unload handler like `$(window).unload(function(){});` to disable the cache.

More info here: http://madhatted.com/2013/6/16/you-do-not-understand-browser-history

Comment: Is that a special problem at dropdowns?